# How can I configure GitHub Actions to jlink my Java application?

Tags: java, github-actions, jlink

I'm using GitHub Actions and I'd like to package a JavaFX application via jlink.

But I get this error during the maven build: `Error: Hash of javafx.base (<hash>) differs to expected hash (<other-hash>) recorded in java.base`

On my developer machine everything is fine, so I guess it has something to do with the jdk?

I already tried to use the `jdk+fx`, provided by the [Setup Java Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-java-jdk), but without any effect.

It also appears on Linux, Windows and Mac OS.

Is there any configuration that I overlooked? Thanks!